# How can I transfer photos on Samsung galaxy note 2 to computer?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-2, mtp, data-transfer

How can I transfer photos on Samsung galaxy note 2 to computer? I'd like use my new note 2 cell phone to take photos, So I want to backup all the pictures to the computer. I can't do this easily since USB mass storage is not supported natively in the Samsung galaxy note 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily using an app such as [SG USB Mass Storage Enabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mohammadag.samsungusbmassstorageenabler). As you already know, your device does not support mass storage facility. So You have to ask help from MTP modes or enable the Mass Storage mode.

The app stated above does the latter. It is easy. *But* you have to have the root access. If you don't know how, use [this guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2143479) to know how.

Answer (score 2):

i just asked asked a similar question at [Move photos from Android to PC wirelessly *in one step*](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77004/move-photos-from-android-to-pc-wirelessly-in-one-step)

after becoming frustrated that the seemingly common task of moving photos from a phone to a pc (crazy, i know) was met with suggestions ranging from rooting and tweaking the phone to adb to cumbersome file transfers (fine for us techies, not fine for e.g. my grandmother), i found ...

- **TL;DR:** [Photo Transfer App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phototransfer)
- Optional: Application for Windows side (www.phototransferapp.com/win/) or Application for Mac side (www.phototransferapp.com/mac/). if you dont install them (or are using Linux) you can just connect to the phone in a web browser.

... which does almost exactly this, except it cant delete photos off the phone (not that i can tell anyways). at the time of this writing it is a reasonable $2 usd. as a bonus it supports phone-to-phone and pc-to-phone transfers as well.

its faster than airdroid and good when theres no internet connection; also the pc-side software can autodetect the device and gives clear access to photos, and doesnt require any rooting or special features or anything like that. if it could delete the photos it would be perfect.

airdroid kinda works too but relays the files through an internet connection, which given current (i.e. past 15 years) technology isnt actually necessary to transfer photos from a phone to a pc.

thank god there are still some sane developers left in this world.

Comment: (I'd link the apps but i dont have enough rep right now; somebody feel free to edit)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using [mtp](/questions/tagged/mtp), if you have trouble with that, there are several alternatives you could use. The easiest probably is a tool like [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid), which simply runs on your Android device, and can be accessed from your computer using your web browser. Another possibility (which I use regularly) is [QtADB](http://qtadb.wordpress.com/), which requires a little setup on your computer (see: [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)), and *USB Debugging* enabled on your Android device. *QtADB contains a file manager, which allows you to easily transfer files to and from your device, and also to install `*.apk` files directly from your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: (Easier) 
If the two devices are connected to the same Wifi network, you could transfer files to and from the Note 2 via an app called Airdroid. It's actually quite easy to use. After installation on the Note 2, just follow the instructions. You'll need to open a browser, such as Chrome, and navigate to the url displayed on the Note 2.

Option 2:
If you want to get techy, I've figured out a way to turn my tablet into a mini HTTP server using Python and the SL4A scripting layer. After a little bit of setting up, just run the script and navigate to your mobile device's IP address. Then make your way to the files on the device, right-click and save. Zipping the files you want to transfer on the device first saves you a lot of time. If you need to find out your device's IP address, you can use an app called Wifi Analyzer.

Here's the link for the [SL4A scripting layer](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/). Please follow the Python instructions.

P.S. 
Make sure you only so this on a secure network. Anyone with your device's IP address would be able to access your files.